# Accessing CSV File in Different Directory (Python)

Tags: python

I have my data in the file 'Climate\Data\Raw_Flooding\CSV\input\addresses.csv'

My code which needs to access the file, however, is in the folder 'Climate\Code\Flooding\python_code\code.py'

How do I access the data subdirectory when I am in the code subdirectory?

Comment: Look up a tutorial that explains relative paths and absolute paths. [This one's pretty good](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/file-interaction.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import os   
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
path = cwd.split('\\')
new_path = ''
for i in range(path.index('Climate')):
    new_path += path[i]+'\\'
new_path+='Data\Raw_Flooding\CSV\input\\address.csv'
print(new_path)
```

This will give you the path to the csv file.

Comment: I am getting an error saying "unexpected character after line continuation character". I think it has to do with the new directory not in the same green color that the current directory is in. It looks like there is something wrong with how the first string ends and the second string starts.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `.replace`. it should be `data_path=cwd.replace('\Code\Flooding\python_code\','\Data\Raw_Flooding\CSV\input\',1)` I just edited my answer.

Comment: I'm still getting the "unexpected character after line continuation character" error. The string for the new directory still isn't green, indicating it's not being detected as a string.

Comment: I will try later this afternoon, '\' will be tricky to deal with. Which operating system are you using,

Comment: windows is the OS

Comment: I just updated my answer, I tested it. it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If my answer helped you. Can you select it as the answer to the question. Thx!